# Android resources different value when pass to the function

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-resources, android-jetpack

Can anyone explain why the value of a android resource id (R.id.navigation_news) before and after passing to a function is different?

[Before pass to function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrdS8.jpg)

```
  fun showTabFragment() {
    navigateWithStartDest(R.id.navigation_news) // R.id.navigation_news == -1000386
  }
```

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoOEx.jpg)

```
  fun navigateWithStartDest(resId:Int){
    //resId == 2131362119
    //resId != R.id.navigation_news - true
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Please write your code in question instead of sharing images links.

Comment: @BaselIssmail I added sample code

Comment: You see negative value?

Comment: @AIMINPAN yes,  and in navigateWithStartDest func, R.id.navigation_news != resId. This is strange. This is not a big problem for my application. But I would like to understand the reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you get integer overflow. The reason is your integer is too big.

> In computer programming, an integer overflow occurs when an arithmetic operation attempts to create a numeric value that is outside of the range that can be represented with a given number of digits – either larger than the maximum or lower than the minimum representable value.

See the link: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

The solution is not operate on `R.id` values, but only pass them as resources.

Answer (score 0):

It could occur because of Java memory model. In kotlin language all primitives turned into objects. So in your function you receive not exact value but reference for it.